# IF condition based on wp_remote_get output

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, shortcode

I'm working on a plugin for displaying content based on the Letter Show in API. Where I want to display the content based on A or B returned by the API.

I have created an API here: https://randletter2020.herokuapp.com

The API only displays A or B at a time.

This is the plugin code I have created. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. "A Wins" is not displaying in `[letter]` I don't know if the API is pinging or not.

I have a bit of coding knowledge. Not an expert. Help me please to fix the issue in my code. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
/**
* Plugin Name: Based on Random Letter
* Plugin URI: https://randletter2020.herokuapp.com
* Description: Desc.
* Version: 1.0
* Author: Ava
* Author URI: https://randletter2020.herokuapp.com
**/
ob_start();
function initapi(){
$api_url = "https://randletter2020.herokuapp.com";
$wp_response = wp_remote_get($api_url);
if($wp_response){
$contents = wp_remote_retrieve_body($wp_response);
}

if ($contents) {
$json = json_decode($contents, 1);
if ($json == "a") {

function set_letter(){
  $letter = "A Wins";
  return $letter;
}
add_shortcode('letter', 'set_letter');
}
else {   
        return false;
        //Do nothing
   }
 }
}
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'initapi' );
```

Comment: May I know what is the intent of this plugin? Why you are using rest_api_init hook?

Comment: Then main intent of the plugin is to Change the content according to the API Response. I thought rest_api_init hook will help because I'm requesting from API.

Comment: rest_api_init hook is used to perform api operation on your WordPress site. Example: Registering a new endpoint.

Comment: Oh, I understood. What others I have change in my code to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Following would be the revised example code which you may want to try.

```
function display_api_response() {
    $api_url = "https://randletter2020.herokuapp.com";
$response = wp_remote_get($api_url);
   if ( 200 === wp_remote_retrieve_response_code($response) ) {
        $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);

        if ( 'a' === $body ) {
          echo 'A wins';
        }else {
          // Do something else.
        }
   }
}
add_action( 'init', 'display_api_response' );
```

Here, you may want to replace `init` action with something else suitable to your requirements.

Please refer wp hooks for appropriate actions: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Comment: Thank you Ankit. This works really awesome. How can I cache that value in my site (client side) for 5 minutes? Is it possible?

Comment: If client side caching for 5 minutes is possible the API Calls will be in the interval of 5 mins right? Because I want to display same result for 5 Minute. Pinging API changes the API Output value

Comment: In this case, your website is client for the API, so you can use `set_transient` from wordpress: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/set_transient/